# Having problems building an Emotional Intelligence Application using Python version 3.8.5 on PyCharm with the TensorFlow and Keras Libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm, python-3.8

This application tracks the emotions of faces Realtime using the camera. Open CV is used for drawing rectangles and overlaying text data. Face emotion recognition will be using Deep Face library where the webcam identifies human faces in digital images.

The versions of the Tensorflow and Keras libraries are both 2.2.0

**I am getting this error at the moment:**

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

in 
1 import cv2
2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 from deepface import DeepFace
4
5 faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

d:\myenv\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py in 
10 import pickle
11
---> 12 from deepface.basemodels import VGGFace, OpenFace, Facenet, FbDeepFace, DeepID, DlibWrapper, ArcFace, Boosting
13 from deepface.extendedmodels import Age, Gender, Race, Emotion
14 from deepface.commons import functions, realtime, distance as dst

d:\myenv\lib\site-packages\deepface\basemodels\VGGFace.py in 
10         from keras.layers import Input, Convolution2D, ZeroPadding2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Activation
11 else:
---> 12         from tensorflow import keras
13         from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
14         from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Convolution2D, ZeroPadding2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Activation

d:\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras_*init*_.py in 
27 from . import models
28 from . import optimizers
---> 29 from . import preprocessing
30 from . import regularizers
31 from . import utils

d:\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\preprocessing_*init*_.py in 
10 from . import image
11 from . import sequence
---> 12 from . import text
13
14 del _print_function

d:\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\preprocessing\text_*init*_.py in 
13 from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
14 from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence
---> 15 from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import tokenizer_from_json
16
17 del _print_function

ImportError: cannot import name 'tokenizer_from_json' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text' (d:\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\text.py)

I tried fixing the issue by uninstalling and installing different versions of tenderflow and keras but it is still not working. Is there a kind sole that has encountered with this kind of issue and can help me please ?

```
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
#Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read() #Read one image from a video
    result = DeepFace.analyze(frame, actions=['emotion'], enforce_detection=False)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)

    #Draw a rectangle around the faces
    #Draw a rectangle around the faces

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0),2)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    #inserting text on video
    cv2.putText(frame,
            result['dominant_emotion'],
            (50,50),
            font,3,
            (0,0,255),
            2,
            cv2.LINE_4)
    cv2.imshow('Demo video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use its stream function?

```
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/my_db")
```

Here, my_db should store the facial images but if you don't want to apply face recognition, then pass it to an empty folder. Then, it will track facial expressions.